# How to call draw rect method to draw different shapes on a single button click?

Tags: iphone, ios5

I am having a button in `UIViewController` and i want to call `drawRect` method of `UIView` to draw different shapes on a button click of `UIViewController`.

Answer (score 1):

To answer first part of your question: how to call `drawRect` method.

You don't call this method directly, you simply call `[view setNeedsDisplay];`

As for the second part of your question. You don't *tell* `drawRect` what to draw via parameters - you override it and draw the objects you need by yourself.

You can find a nice tutorial here: [An iPhone Graphics Drawing Tutorial using Quartz 2D](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iPhone_Graphics_Drawing_Tutorial_using_Quartz_2D)

Answer (score 1):

rokjarc's answer is correct and you should accept his answer, not mine.  I'm just elaborating.

I suggest you view lectures 5 and 6 of the Stanford CS193P 2011 course.

http://itunes.apple.com/itunes-u/ipad-iphone-application-development/id473757255

Lecture 5 is mostly drawing, lecture 6 hooks up the drawRect to a slider.

**edit** credit to rokjarc